# How to get more events running with asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio

I am currently learning asynchronous programming and wrote this program that will send requests asynchronously with python 3 asyncio.
When running it, my program is not that fast, I was trying to figure out how to do better.

To find the number of events running I thought about checking my kernel task thread number in the Activity Monitor. It appears I am only running 222 threads for a total of 2% of he CPU.

Is there a way to max the thread count ?

Can I make it faster by having a cleaner code ? As seen below my code is working but kind of hacky.

```
import asyncio
import requests

def main():
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        for i in enumerate(list):
            f = loop.run_in_executor(make_request())
            if i == end:
                response = yield from f

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at an asyncio tutorial such as [this one](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/), and switch from requests to an asyncio-compatible library, such as [this one](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/).

Comment: Thank you for answering! With further research it seems like the requests.get is the blocking part indeed.